# Where is ExtBase reference material available?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am searching for a good source for understanding the `userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run` magic incantation.

The seemingly autoritative documentation on forge (http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/Documentation) starts off with non-functional links ("400 - Invalid action parameter" from git.typo3.org) and seems dated, pointing to articles with the newest date in late 2011.

The API doc at http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_core_1_1_bootstrap.html#a890c7dde66b4a9462983759de4d9576a is rather sparse as to what the "TS configuration array" might contain. It also seems a little odd to list two sets of arguments and two different return informations, it is almost as if two methods were concatenated in one entry. Trying to follow the source code leads to initilializeConfiguration where it seems to hand over control to some general routine.

There is a revision e6c08008 committed "over a year ago" which claims to have updated the docs to the current URL, which is supposed to be http://api.typo3.org/extbase/current/ - but this only leads to a page with lots of classes and blank frames with no content. This is the URL that is offered in my copy downloaded a few months ago as well.

So: Where might it be that I can learn how to utilize this extbase bootstrap run method? Source code is fine, but I am not able to determine where the config is actually digested.

Answer (score 1):

The Extbase bootstrap can be used to use an Extbase plugin via TypoScript. Which configuration is needed to achieve that (using TYPO3 6.x) can be seen here:
[Assign plugin in typoscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999395/assign-plugin-in-typoscript?answertab=active#tab-top)

This may also be a source - the Fluid and Extbase book, unfortunately not all chapters are translated to english yet (and it is based on TYPO3 4.x):
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/singlehtml/#bootstrap

This is covering the SwitchableControllerActions:
http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/Dispatcher_rework

[Use Extbase Plugin in TypoScript](http://alt.mimi.kaktusteam.de/index.php?id=mimis_blog&tx_t3blog_pi1%5BblogList%5D%5BshowUid%5D=178&tx_t3blog_pi1%5BblogList%5D%5Byear%5D=2011&tx_t3blog_pi1%5BblogList%5D%5Bmonth%5D=01&tx_t3blog_pi1%5BblogList%5D%5Bday%5D=25&cHash=e40ea53a61006c55812d676921a27709)

Comment: Thanks a lot, lorenz, but even as valuable stackoverflows bits and pieces are, it is hardly a systematic reference. The Fluid and Extbase book tries to do good, but e.g. a question like "What is it with the switchableControllerActions vs the more terse action parameter" is not answered. And what else might there be, that nobody mentions?

Comment: Well, I'm not responsible for the lack of information :-)... I added two more sources referring to bootstrap and the SwitchableControllerActions.

Comment: I am sorry if it sounded like I hold you responsible for the lack of information, this was not at all my intention! I am grateful and thank you for your links which are great, but still do not constitute any reference grade documentation. I will keep looking, I have dug deeper into the Classes/Configuration/*ConfigurationManager.php classes and found some of the parameters there, but not all.